# How to know which UITextField is responding?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uitextview

In the `UIViewController` I add itself as observer:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];

    ......
}

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification {

    NSDictionary *userInfo = [notification userInfo];
    NSValue* aValue = [userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey];
    CGRect keyboardRect = [aValue CGRectValue];

    if (textField1.isFirstResponder) {
        NSLog(@"I am here1");
    }

    if (textField2.isFirstResponder) {
        NSLog(@"I am here2");
    }

     ........

}
```

I also create five `UITextField` in the controller. My problem is how to know which textField is called. I try the method to find out whose "isFirstResponder" have change , but it is not working.

Comment: isFirstResponder is working perfectly fine for me.(I just tested it) If you are changing the textField while keyboard is visible, the notification will not be received and method will not be called. Check by hiding the keyboard before you click on other textField.

Comment: @Ad-J I have to say sorry that isFirstResponder is really working! I have make a stupied mistake!

Comment: I make a mistake. I have solved the question.

Answer (score 4):

erm... why don't you use `-textFieldDidBeginEditing:` of `UITextFieldDelegate`

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSLog(@"%@",textField);
}
```

Comment: There are legitamate reasons to use notfications instead of the delegate methods. Each of these get called at different points of the lifecycle

Comment: @Cutetare : yes, possible but the question seems _in general_ to me rather than related to the `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification`  notification (even though his code includes it)

Answer (score 1):

Use the tag property!! When you create your Textfield set their tags (to some textfield-specific number), and when you get the notification, simply check which tag they have!

Answer (score 0):

Try UIKeyboardDidShowNotification instead of UIKeyboardWillShowNotification.